# How to add a custom header to cxf soap requests?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I'd like to create the following xml by using `cxf` and `spring` soap webservices:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:key="http://schema.to/WebService">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <key:Signing>asdasdasd</key:Signing>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

How can this be done? How can I set the namespace and the custom header tag element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following in the maven cxf configuration:

```
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>...</wsdl>
    <extraargs>  
        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg> <!-- this -->
        <extraarg>true</extraarg> <!-- this -->
    </extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
```

This generates method attributes `@WebParam(header = true)` which then can be provided on webservice access.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CustomHeaderHandler that implements `javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`
In `public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMsgCtx)` use code like this

```
if (msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader() == null) {
    msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
}
msg.getSOAPHeader().addChildElement("Signing", "key").addTextNode("asdasdasd");
```